# Proof of Bellman Optimality Equation

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, reinforcement-learning

Following Barto and Sutton's "Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction", I am having trouble rigorously proving the Bellman Optimality Equation for finite MDPs.

Namely, why does $v_*(s) = \max\limits_{a \in A(s)} q_{\pi_*}(s, a)$?

My attempt to see this is true:

Let $v_* := \max\limits_{a \in A(s)} q_{\pi_*}(s, a)$

$v_*(s) = \sum\limits_{a \in A(s)} \pi_*(a | s) q_{\pi_*}(s, a) \leq v_*$

However, I'm not sure I see why equality must hold. I'm thinking that we construct $\pi'$ such that $\pi'(s) \in \arg\max \limits_{a \in A(s)} q_{\pi_*}(s, a)$, $\pi(s') = \pi_*(s')$ $\forall s' \neq s$ and show that $v_\pi(s) = v_*$?.

Intuitively I see this statement being true if we allow non-stationary policies and that stationary rewards should mean that we could "just take" our policy to be stationary, but I don't see the clear reasoning behind this.

In a similar vein, why does does $\pi_*(s) = \arg\max \limits_{a \in A(s)} q_{\pi_*}(s, a)$ constitute an optimal policy?

Answer (score 3):

Before answering your question. We need to introduce the following relationship. Let's first take a look at the definitions of value function and action value function under policy $\pi$:
\begin{align}
 &v_{\pi}(s)=E{\left[G_t|S_t=s\right]} \\
 &q_{\pi}(s,a)=E{\left[G_t|S_t=s, A_t=a\right]}
\end{align}
where $G_t=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\gamma^kR_{t+k+1}$ is the return at time $t$. The relationship between these two value functions can be derived as
\begin{align}
  v_{\pi}(s)&=E{\left[G_t|S_t=s\right]} \nonumber \\
  &=\sum_{g_t} p(g_t|S_t=s)g_t \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{g_t}\sum_{a}p(g_t, a|S_t=s)g_t \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{a}p(a|S_t=s)\sum_{g_t}p(g_t|S_t=s, A_t=a)g_t \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{a}p(a|S_t=s)E{\left[G_t|S_t=s, A_t=a\right]} \nonumber \\
  &= \sum_{a}p(a|S_t=s)q_{\pi}(s,a) \qquad (1)
\end{align}
The above equation is important. It describes the relationship between two fundamental value functions in reinforcement learning. It is valid for any policy. Moreover, if we have a deterministic policy, then $v_{\pi}(s)=q_{\pi}(s,\pi(s))$.

Now let's start answering your question by recalling the definitions of optimal policy, optimal state-value function, and optimal action-value function:

1. Optimal policy: If $v_{\pi}(s)\ge v_{\pi'}(s)$ for all $s\in \mathcal{S}$, then we say $\pi$ is better than or equal to $\pi'$. There is always at least one policy that is better than or equal to all other policies. This is an optimal policy.
2. Optimal state-value function: $\displaystyle v_*(s)=\max_{\pi}v_{\pi}(s)$, $\forall s\in\mathcal{S}$.
3. Optimal action-value function: $\displaystyle q_*(s, a)=\max_{\pi}q_{\pi}(s, a)$, $\forall s\in\mathcal{S}$ and $a\in A(s)$.

Now, let's assume we already know $q_*(s, a)$, then the following deterministic policy is apparently an optimal policy. 
\begin{align}
 p(a|s)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle
 1, \quad a=\text{argmax}_{a\in A(s)}q_*(s, a)\\
 0, \quad \text{else}
 \end{cases}\label{o1}
\end{align}
In practice, we can only focus on deterministic policies since there always exists at least one deterministic policy that is optimal. By using this deterministic optimal policy in Eq. (1), we can obtain the following important relationship:
\begin{align}
 v_{*}(s)=\max_{a\in A(s)}q_*(s, a)
\end{align}
This is the famous Bellman optimality equation.

Comment: I am not sure if Jie Shi answer is an answer at all: first of all, it is not clear at all what is $p$ in the derivation of Eq. 1. I am guessing that you are referring to this relation between value and state-value functions for policies: $$v_{\pi}(s) = \sum_{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)} \pi(a|s) q_{\pi}(s,a)$$ But then if you define your deterministic policy $p$ as you have done, what you get by applying the previous relation to it is simply $$v_{p}(s) = q_{p}(s,a_s)$$ where $a_s \in \text{argmax}_{a \in \mathcal{A}(s)} q_*(s,a)$

Comment: To your first concern,   $p(\cdot)$ denotes probability distribution. Policy is, intrinsically speaking, distribution of action condition on state. In this sense, $p$ and $\pi$ can be used interchangeably. Hope you now understand how Eq. 1 comes.                        To your second concern,  What you have written is equivalent to the result that we want to prove.

Comment: Do you have a similar derivation as (1) showing how $q_{\pi}(s,a)$ can be expressed as $v_{\pi}(s)$?

Comment: To endbegin: Unfortunately, we do not have an inverse version of this relationship. But we do have the following one: $V_{\pi}(s)=Q_{\pi}(s,a)-A(s,a)$ where $A(s,a)$ is called advantage function.

Comment: @JieShi I don't get why the $p$ you defined is an optimal policy.

Comment: @JieShi Moreover, $q_p(s,a)$ is not even defined.